# Porque overlay-container bloquea la página

Tags: html, angular, materialize

Buen día. Tengo un proyecto angular, y en ningún momento le he agregado un`div class="overlay-container"`. Pero al inspeccionar en el navegador, se carga este div, y bloquea la pagina, no deja clickear nada, básicamente me toca desde el inspector eliminar ese elemento para que deje seguir trabajando. Pero es bastante molesto, el estar inspeccionando y teniendo que eliminar cada vez que recargo la pagina.

```html
<div class="overlay-container">
   <div id="toast-container" class="md-toast-top-right">
</div>
</div>
```

Ese es el código que se carga cuando inspecciono. Al mirar estilos muestra varios de materialize, agradecería si me dicen como remover esto del todo o evitar que se cargue al inspeccionar. Gracias.

Comment: Debe ser algo agregado por Materialize, si remueves la biblioteca debería dejar de aparecer ese div.

Comment: Puede ser, el detalle es que para otra parte del proyecto necesito usar elementos de esa biblioteca

Answer (score 0):

Angular material crea ese div fuera del `app-root` en el `body` algo asi:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <div class="overlay-container">
  </div>
</body>
```

Este es un comportamiento normal ya que Angular Material crea en ese div varios de sus compomentes, por ejemplo si estas usando componentes de material como ser **tooltips, dialogs o autocomplete panel** estos son creados en ese div.

Si se te queda en negro y bloquea toda tu pagina lo mas probable es que no estes importanto correctamente los estilos de angular material, primero asegurate de tener la libreria instalada y luego de tener un tema importando en tu archivo `styles.scss` debes tener algo como esto:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

Así todas las clases serán importadas de forma correcta y no deberías tener ese tipo de problemas.